# Install LiDAR Terrestrial Point Cloud Processing of Forest Data package does work

Tags: r, r-package, lidar

I try install TreeLS package, but i receive this message.

```
install.packages("TreeLS")

Message: 

Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Matheus Pacheco/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.2’
Warning in install.packages :
package ‘TreeLS’ is not available for this version of R
A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages
```

I found that the package is not present in CRAN anymore, and i try install from source, using:

```
install.packages("TreeLS", repos = "https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/TreeLS/TreeLS_2.0.2.tar.gz", repo = NULL, type="source")
```

But, some functions in the package, doesn't work.

I would be grateful if someone can help me. My final paper in PhD depends on it.

Thanks!

Comment: If it works, what is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that if you're using a **retired** package, there is little help to get unless you try to fix it yourself. The question become too general.

> But, some functions in the package, doesn't work.

- Contact package developer, there is probably another package that include what you need, or his code might have been moved into some other package. He/She would know.
- Perhaps someone can help you if you pull out the parts you need.
- last resort (not recommend), downgrade to a compatible R version.